# Understanding problem regarding operated streams in Java

Tags: java, java-stream, illegalstateexception

Let's say we have the following code

```
Stream<Integer> ints = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
    
ints.peek(System.out::println);
    
ints.forEach(System.out::println);
```

and I run it, I'll get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

But why?

`peek` is an intermediate operation, so I thought, that it won't run/start the stream itself? Only `forEach` does this, so why has the stream already been operated when reaching `forEach`?

I also thought, that the `peek` method would be discarded, because it returns a new `Stream` that I do not consider. Like in

```
String str = "hello world";
str.toUppercase();
str.charAt(0); // <-- h not H
```

Comment: Stream is intended to be used like `Stream.of(1,2,3).peek(System.out::println).forEach(System.out::println);`, the intermediate `Stream`s are NOT intended to be assigned to variables! Also be aware of the note stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)) of `peek()`: "This method exists mainly to support debugging, ... In cases where the stream implementation is able to optimize away the production of some or all the elements ( ... ), the action will not be invoked for those elements."

Comment: @user16320675 The behavior described in the Question is **not** related to `peek` specifically.

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`peek` is an ***intermediate operation***, which means it performs an action and produces a **new** Stream. But you're reusing the same Stream, therefore getting an `IllegalStateException`.

Here's a quote, from the [`Stream`'s Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) :

> A stream should be operated on (**invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation**) **only once**. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may throw `IllegalStateException` if it detects that the stream is being reused. However, since some stream operations may return their receiver rather than a new stream object, it may not be possible to detect reuse in all cases.

<sup>Amphesys added</sup>

***Note:** as *@Holger* has pointed out documentation states (see the quote above) that in some cases intermediate stream operation might return the received stream (representing the previous stage) instead of generating a new one.*

If you write the code like this, it would work as intended:

```
Stream<Integer> ints = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
    
Stream<Integer> ints1 = ints.peek(System.out::println);
    
ints1.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which is basically a verbose equivalent of the chain:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3)                 // ints
    .peek(System.out::println)     // ints1
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Your understanding that a Stream would be galvanized into action only if it has a *terminal operation* is correct. And the stream you've presented in the code has a terminal operation.

But it's worth to note that the exception occurs not while executing the stream, but while **preparing** the pipeline. I.e. when the Stream instance is being initialized.

There's an internal class `AbstractPipeline` which we as users of the API not interacting directly, it's purpose defined as follows:

> Abstract base class for "pipeline" classes, which are the core
>
> - implementations of the Stream interface and its primitive
>   specializations.
> - Manages construction and evaluation of stream pipelines

Here's a piece of code from this class (***[link to the source](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/AbstractPipeline.java#L201)***):

```
AbstractPipeline(AbstractPipeline<?, E_IN, ?> previousStage, int opFlags) {
    if (previousStage.linkedOrConsumed)    // <- Note
        throw new IllegalStateException(MSG_STREAM_LINKED);
    previousStage.linkedOrConsumed = true; // <- Note
    previousStage.nextStage = this;
    
    this.previousStage = previousStage;
    this.sourceOrOpFlags = opFlags & StreamOpFlag.OP_MASK;
    this.combinedFlags = StreamOpFlag.combineOpFlags(opFlags, previousStage.combinedFlags);
    this.sourceStage = previousStage.sourceStage;
    if (opIsStateful())
        sourceStage.sourceAnyStateful = true;
    this.depth = previousStage.depth + 1;
}
```

In this implementation, each operation is represented as a stage. And stages are linked with each other. While constructing the next stage a link to next stage should be provided and `boolean` property `linkedOrConsumed` of the previous stage is being to `true`. If the previous stage has been already linked (*which has happened in your code*) the constructor throws an exception.

For that reason, even the following code, which lacks terminal operation, would trigger an `IllegalStateException` (JDK 17, HotSpot JVM). It would take place during the preparation of the `Stream` object (***not** while executing the pipeline*).

```
Stream<Integer> ints = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);

ints.map(i -> i * i);
ints.takeWhile(i -> i % 2 != 0); // exception would be thrown while initializing this stage
```

***Note:** this information is an implementation detail, and proved purely as explanation of the behavior OP has encountered. And the code snippet with a Stream with no terminal operation certainly is not guaranteed to behave this way (for instance, some implementation might simply discard it). The bottom line here is that a Stream should be consumed only once.*

Comment: Note that in general, intermediate operations are free to either, return a new Stream instance or modify the existing one and return it. Hence, the caller always must use the object returned by the method and assume the old reference to be invalid, to comply with all possible strategies. Compare with [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#:~:text=A%20stream%20should,in%20all%20cases.): “*… implementation may throw IllegalStateException… …some stream operations may return their receiver rather than a new stream object,…*”